# Issues adding texture to Reality Converter?

Tags: realitykit, reality-composer, reality-converter

Anyone having issues with Reality Converter by Apple. Mainly, when I add an `.obj` file, it’s able to display the white object. However, when I go ahead and add a texture `.png` files into the Materials folder, nothing gets updated. I end up with a plain white 3d object (even after restarting/exporting).

The only way it works is if I upload a `.gITF` folder, where it will actually add in the textures/color.

Not sure if this is a glitch? Or if I’m doing something wrong?

Comment: Ever found a solution to this problem, please? having the exact same issues getting textures or even materials into Reality Composer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply a texture to `.obj` file you need not only a texture file but also its inseparable companion `.mtl` file ([Material Template Library](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000508.shtml)) – a special material definitions file for `.obj`.